# Sqlite can i use nester cursors?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to do a query with in a query

`id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SUBJECT_ID));
S = new Subject(id, getSubjectDescById(id));
Subjects.add(S);`

the getSubjectDescById() function opens up another cursor on its own.
mCursor is opened before the code and closed after it.
Is it risky to have nested Cursors? If so what would be a better alternative to my code

Comment: multiple/nested cursors for querying from the same table?

Comment: no I'm using the first cursor to go one table.
The second cursor is used to take a value from the first cursor and get something from another table

Comment: I didn't get what you said exactly. Be more specific and put more details into your question.

Comment: Can i use nested cursors?
Cursor1 open-->{Cursor2 open-->Cursor2 close}-->Cursor1 close
cursor 1 and 2 go to different tables

Comment: This works fine (but you should consider using a join).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***`I have not tested this though but i think,Yes you can use Nested cursors`***

---

**`Scenario`**:

- *`Step-1>`* Open CURSOR-1
- *`Step-2>`* Open CURSOR-2 and Use that cursor as a pointer for the new Cursor you care going to create
- *`Step-3>`* Close CURSOR-2
- *`Step-4>`* Close Cursor-1

---

***Try this Sample***::

```
private void DemoFunction() throws Exception {
        DatabaseHandler mHelper;
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        Cursor mCursor1 = null;
        Cursor mCursor2 = null;
        try {
            mHelper = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
            db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            //make query for buffet-type 
            mCursor1 = db.rawQuery("<------My First Query ------>", null);
            if(mCursor1.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    mCursor2 = db.rawQuery("<------My Second Query ------>", null);
                    if(mCursor2.moveToFirst()){
                    do{


                    }while(mCursor2.moveToNext());
                    Log.d("", "");
                  }
                }while(mCursor1.moveToNext());
                Log.d("", "");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(isErr==false){
                errMsg=e.getLocalizedMessage();
                isErr=true;
            }
            throw e;
        }finally{
            if(db!=null){
                if(db.isOpen()) db.close();
            }
            if(mCursor1!=null||mCursor2!=null){
                if(!mCursor2.isClosed())mCursor2.close();
                if(!mCursor1.isClosed())mCursor1.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

***Note***:- *Make sure you close all the cursors*